# java code samples illustrating usage of amazon dynamo db

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Are you aware of java code samples illustrating usage of Amazon Dynamo DB?
If there are any recommended best practices, that would also be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) has a very simple [example for DynamoDB](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/src/samples/AmazonDynamoDB) that I used as a jumping off point ([direct SDK download link](http://ds60ft5bv5jal.cloudfront.net/latest/aws-java-sdk.zip)) - the source is available via GitHub as well, see [/samples/AmazonDynamoDB/AmazonDynamoDBSample.java](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AmazonDynamoDB/AmazonDynamoDBSample.java).

Comment: I was searching for same Thanks.

Comment: links giving 404, please update your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Check also [jcabi-dynamo](http://dynamo.jcabi.com/index.html), which is an object layer on top of AWS DynamoDB Java SDK, for example:

```
Region region = new Region.Simple(credentials);
Table table = region.table("my-table");
Collection<Item> items = table.frame().where("name", "Jeff");
for (Item item : items) {
  System.out.println(item.get("salary").getS());
}
```

Comment: How do we write JSON using this api? E.g with AWS we can do new Item().withJSON(attrName, json)

Comment: I think we can extend the library to support JSON natively, submit a suggestion to Github, we'll do it: https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-dynamo